# SSL TLS Version issue in BigQuery Linked Service in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am creating a Linked Service to connect to BigQuery with Service Account authentication and p12 file has already been placed in IR VM directory.

Receiving following error:
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverSupport] (1160) Cannot enable SSL for the connection when connecting to a server that has not enabled SSL. If the server has SSL enabled, please check if it has been configured to use a SSL protocol version that is lower than what is allowed for the connection. The minimum SSL protocol version allowed for the connection is: TLS 1.2.

But when i place p12 file in another IR VM, linked service is working correctly.

Tried to check TLS version in both VM's and everything looks same.

Please suggest ways to check SSL and TLS version in VM's and how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message it seems the issue might be w.r.t SSL certificate so 1st step would be to compare the SSL/TLS across both the servers

In case if they are same, would suggest to monitor the traffic across both the server when trying to access GCP Big Query.
You might get the exact cause of failure which can be like :

1. Firewall blockage
2. some missing set up like Big query need Google_base set up as a signature
   etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a PowerShell script that checks the TLS & SSL registry entries mentioned in the following documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings

Even if after enabling TLS/SSL settings the same issue arises then please try re-installing IR in the VM